# How to handle not found errors for belongsTo relationship in Ember.Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have Ember application with custom Ember.Data adapter. I have models A and B and one way relationship between them.

```
App.A = DS.Model.extend({
  b: DS.belongsTo('b')
});
```

Problem is that model B can be deleted on the backend without integration checks (this is not a problem). Problem is that now when loading model A it also tries to look up relationship with id=X, but the record is missing. So Ember.Data creates automatically an empty record for model B with id=X, that messes up my data. When listing all models B, this empty record also shows up.

I currently detect that record is not found in extractSingle method in my adapter and throw a new Ember.Error.

What is correct way how to handle this situation? Filtering records manually by isEmpty, isLoading or some other property? There seems to be some notFound event, should I catch this and do something? Should I define relationship as async, will that help to solve this situation?

Comment: I don't recall ember-data's default behaviour being that it would look up the `B` record automatically; if your server returns payload for the `A` record with a `null` `b` property, then `a.get('b')` would simply be null, which you can of course check quite easily throughout your application.

Comment: The case is that server returns A record with b_id property being 123, then Ember-Data tries automatically to look up record B with id 123, but there is no such record. Now instead of leaving A.b null or undefined Ember-Data automatically generates B record with id=123, but all other fields being empty. This is not expected behavior, A.b should be null or undefined in such case.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think that sort of behaviour (on your server) is one not well-supported by ember-data at the moment. What might work better is to just have an 'archived' boolean on your `b` model, which you would return as part of its payload. This is what I'm doing for some models in my app currently that require the sort of 'soft-deletion' that you describe. That would seem preferable to mangling with the error-handling internals of ember-data, which currently don't have many semantics one could hook into.

Comment: This situation can occur even if server has foreign key integrity checks and FK keys are set to null when referenced record is deleted.

Lets say that one user loads record A (b_id=123) as described in my example and then another user deletes record B. Now if user A wants to access record B then the same thing happens. With async relationships this is pretty common scenario. If Ember-Data now creates automatically record B with empty data then this seems like a bug for me.

Comment: I created JSBin for this.
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/guxedihi/2/
I need that A.b.id would be null not 123 as this record is already deleted. I will write issue to Github, but any other temporary solution is also welcome.